# Directive to stop a click not working Angular 2

Tags: angular

When using `HostListener` on a click event and trying to stop the propagation of that event, the click handler on the actual element still fires.

Here's the relevant code and a stackblitz as an example.

```
// Directive
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirective]'
})
export class AppDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event: Event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    alert('i tried to prevent this...');
  }
}

// HTML
<button (click)="doSomething()" appDirective>Click Me</button>

// Click handler
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';

  doSomething() {
    alert('I was not prevented.');
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

https://angular-nufbqg.stackblitz.io

Comment: Another way to do it is to have the directive to listen for click and only propagate its own event based on a condition.

Comment: The issue is that you register two different listeners to the same element. (click) is one and in the directive HostBinding is another one, they are not connected to each other, hence, they wont prevent each other. You have to either use (click) to handle it, or to use the HostBinding in the directive to handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting it wrong, your code does work.

1. What is the default action of a `button` with no type?? Nothing! The method under `(click)` call is not the default action for the browser.
2. You are trying to stop the propagation? There is no listener to the click event above the DOM chain, There is an handler in the same element. So stop propagation is of no use.

You can solve your issue based on what you require. Say, you have to submit a form on the button click. Then a `submit` button types default action would be to submit the form. `preventDefault()` will work there.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="doSomething()">
  <button type="submit" appDirective>Click Me</button>
</form>


export class AppDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event: Event) {
    console.log("host listener called"); // will be called
    $event.preventDefault();
  }
}


doSomething() {
   console.log("do Something called");   // won't be called
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdajrk

Answer (score -1):

```
export class AppDirective {
 @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event']) onClick(evt: Event): boolean {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  alert('i tried to prevent this...');
  return false;
 }
}
```

you have to returned false

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nufbqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.directive.ts Didn't work :(

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x3s9qw?file=src/app/app.directive.ts

Comment: This won't work, and either way, its not a click event its an mousedown, which is anyway not the answer... I won't downvote, but take it into consideration.

Answer (score -1):

I'm accepting Ashish's answer because I am technically doing something incorrectly, but for now I'm just going to disable pointer events on the element where that directive is to get the functionality I want (don't really want a workaround like form-submit).